# Табуляция в файле css

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

Как сделать табуляцию в данном файле с помощью VS Code ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Установить какой-то плагин, а затем использовать определённую комбинацию клавиш для табуляции. Допустим этот плагин: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.beautify. Или же `Prettier`)

Comment: Я тоже Beautify юзаю, удобная штука, но это как-кому, ставьте сначала этот или иной который минификацию раскроет назад и все. Там кучу плагинов есть в VSC

Comment: Я случайно перевел взгляд вправо...

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что не относиться к программированию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Устанавливаете расширение, например, [CSS Formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aeschli.vscode-css-formatter) (по умолчанию в VS Code formatter для CSS файлов отсутствует).

Затем нажимаете `Alt`+`Shift`+`F`.